# フラグが立っているものを優先して取得するクエリ

Tags: mysql

例えば、orderはcreated_atですが、flag=trueのものだけ先に取得して、次にそれ以外を取得したい場合、どういう風にクエリを投げるのがシンプルでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

フラグはブーリアンのカラムだったら、普通のソートで十分だと思います：

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY flag DESC, created_at;
```

ブーリアンではない場合、MySQLの[`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)でブーリアンに変換できます：

```
SELECT *
FROM t
ORDER BY IF(flag = 'xxx', 1, 0) DESC, created_at;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY IF(flag = 'xxx', 1, 0)`は便利ですが効率は？`select 1,t.* from t where flag='xxx'union all select 2,t.* from t where not flag='xxx' order by 1` に比べると

Answer (score 1):

`order by flag desc, created_at`じゃダメですか？

2回投げるのなら素直に`where flag=true`と`where flag=false`になるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど。もし、条件がflag=trueではなくid=xxxで同じ事がしたい場合はよい方法をご存知でしょうか？

Comment: やるならID、created_atの順にorder byかけてやって、後は取得側で対応するのが良いかと思います。大事なのは、どこまでSQLにお願いするか？ってトコだと思います。力技ならなんぼでもやりようあるので。